# Define variable - use in WP loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm trying to output a WP loop with a (class name) variable which changes depending on which iteration it is, as defined in this regex.

```
$mod = 0;
$rows = 0;

 for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {

        $output = " ";

        if ($rows % 2 == 1) {
                    $output = "flip";
        }


           // Build the post - includes the variable $output
       get_template_part( 'partials/loop', 'main' );

        if (++$mod % 2 == 0) {
                    $mod = 0;
                    ++$rows;
        }
  }
```

But this doesn't work; instead outputting many duplicates of the same posts with no output. 
I'm clearly doing something wrong; maybe approaching the problem in the wrong way.

Tip: The expression tests for every other pair such as 11 - 00 - 11 - 00

**The loop, showing desired variable position:**

```
 <div class="post small-12 medium-6 columns <?php echo $output; ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"> 
              <h2 class="blog-title">
                      <?php the_title(); ?></h2>
           </a>
  </div>  <!-- ends post -->
```

Comment: I don't see any regex here?

Comment: OK - may have misunderstood what to call the % 2 == 0 element. I guess just a test in PHP not really a regex, Nick

Comment: It's an "expression" using the modulus operator.

Comment: Step #1 - get the naming right. You can't rename something into regex out of the blue. The same way a bicycle is not a car, this is not a regex - it's a simple expression. Now, for step #2 - you describe what you **want** the code to do and then what it actually does - thus showing us what's your goal. Now what I have to ask is - do you need to check whether the iteration is odd or even?

Comment: Thanks NB. No; I'm not checking just for odd or even, just whether the loop number is 3, 4, 7, 8, 11, 12 etc (odd pairs?). 

Similar code works in 'run your PHP' and outputs code in pairs...
It's just making it work with a WP loop

Comment: I suppose an easier way of asking this question is to ask how does one add a class to each odd pair in a WP loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a variable to your template via `get_template_part()`. You need to instead `include` your template with:

```
include( locate_template( 'partials/loop-main.php' ) ); 
// or whatever your template name is...
```

However, this also highly depends on where you loop is (since you haven't shown it).

For more information, see [this answer on WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9978/how-to-use-get-template-part).

So in your case, you'd have something like:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ): ?>

    <?php // Your initial iterator/counter logic goes here... ?>

    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php 
            // Test your counter to see if you need to add a class on this post

            // include() the template, rather than get_template_part() so that we can pass the
            // counter to the partial template.
            include( locate_template( 'partials/loop-main.php' ) );

            // Increment the counter
        ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks rnevius, I have added it above. This is my problem; knowing where the loop actually goes in this scenario.